# Как построить эмиссионный оптический спектр из графика зависимости длины волны от светового потока?

Tags: python

Имеется файл FITS (назовём его spectra.fits) из The ELODIE Archive (http://atlas.obs-hp.fr/elodie/fE.cgi?n=e500&c=i&z=s1d&a=mime:application/fits&o=elodie:20011121/0036). В первом HDU содержатся одномерные данные (56000 точек) о световом потоке. Вот так я построил график зависимости светового потока, люмен от длины волны, ангстрем:

```python
from astropy.io import fits
from matplotlib import pyplot
 
with fits.open("spectra.fits") as hdu_list:
    # BTYPE = 'FLUX-INS' / Type of data  
    raw_intensity = hdu_list[0].data
 
    # CRVAL1 = 4000. / Coordinate at reference pixel
    ref_pixel = hdu_list[0].header["CRVAL1"]
    # CDELT1 = 0.0500000007 / Coordinate increment (prefer CD) 
    x_increment = hdu_list[0].header["CDELT1"]
    frequencies = list()
    for i in range(0, 56000):
        frequencies.append(ref_pixel)
        ref_pixel += x_increment
 
    pyplot.grid()
    pyplot.plot(frequencies, raw_intensity)
    pyplot.show()
```

Здесь можно просмотреть заголовки для первого HDU:

```
SIMPLE  =                    T / file does conform to FITS standard             
BITPIX  =                  -32 / No.Bits per pixel                              
NAXIS   =                    1 / number of data axes                            
NAXIS1  =                56000 / length of data axis 1                          
EXTEND  =                    T / FITS dataset may contain extensions            
COMMENT   FITS (Flexible Image Transport System) format is defined in 'Astronomy
COMMENT   and Astrophysics', volume 376, page 359; bibcode: 2001A&A...376..359H 
COMMENT   FITS (Flexible Image Transport System) format is defined in 'Astronomy
COMMENT   and Astrophysics', volume 376, page 359; bibcode: 2001A&A...376..359H 
COMMENT   FITS (Flexible Image Transport System) format is defined in 'Astronomy
COMMENT   and Astrophysics', volume 376, page 359; bibcode: 2001A&A...376..359H 
COMMENT   FITS (Flexible Image Transport System) format is defined in 'Astronomy
COMMENT   and Astrophysics', volume 376, page 359; bibcode: 2001A&A...376..359H 
CRPIX1  =                   1. / Reference pixel                                
CRVAL1  =                4000. / Coordinate at reference pixel                  
CDELT1  =         0.0500000007 / Coordinate increment (prefer CD)               
VERSION = '1.3     '           / TACOS_VERSION                                  
LASTCOMP= 'tacos_SunOS_5.4 - Thu Mar 7 14:46:32 WET 1996' / TACOS_LASTCOMP      
INSTRUME= 'ELODIE  '           / INSTRUME                                       
ORIGIN  = 'OHP     '           / ORIGIN                                         
CUMUL   =       1.00000000E+00 / O_CUMUL                                        
DATETU  = '20011122'           / O_DATETU                                       
HDEBUT  =       1.84580555E+01 / O_HDEBUT                                       
HFIN    =       1.85247440E+01 / O_HFIN                                         
EXPTIME =           240.740005 / [s] Exposure time                              
TIME1   =       2.00100000E+03 / O_TIME                                         
TIME2   =       1.10000000E+01 / O_TIME                                         
TIME3   =       2.20000000E+01 / O_TIME                                         
TIME4   =       1.84914913E+01 / O_TIME                                         
TIME5   =       2.40740005E+02 / O_TIME                                         
CCDGAIN =       2.65000010E+00 / ELODIE_CCDGAIN                                 
NUMGAIN =       3.00000000E+00 / ELODIE_NUMGAIN                                 
NUMCCD  = '1       '           / ELODIE_NUMCCD                                  
NUMCORRE= '1       '           / ELODIE_NUMCORRE                                
POSCORRE= '161     '           / ELODIE_POSCORRE                                
CCDTEMP = '-89.99  '           / ELODIE_CCDTEMP                                 
CCDPOWER= '61.50   '           / ELODIE_CCDPOWER                                
MAP     = '1894    '           / ELODIE_MAP                                     
OBSERVER= 'catala  '           / OBSERVER                                       
NONUIT  =       3.60000000E+01 / NONUIT                                         
POS1    =       2.26558361E+01 / TEL_POS                                        
POS2    =       3.90663872E+01 / TEL_POS                                        
NOOBJET1=                    1 / CAT_NOOBJET                                    
NOOBJET2=                    0 / CAT_NOOBJET                                    
NOOBJET3=               214680 / CAT_NOOBJET                                    
NOOBJET4=                    0 / CAT_NOOBJET                                    
REFNOCOD= '*       '           / CAT_REFNOCODE                                  
EQUINOX =       2.00000000E+03 / CAT_EQUINOX                                    
ALPHA   = '22:39:16'           / CAT_ALPHA                                      
DELTA   = '+39:03:01'          / CAT_DELTA                                      
PROPERM1=       0.00000000E+00 / CAT_PROPERMVT                                  
PROPERM2=       0.00000000E+00 / CAT_PROPERMVT                                  
NOPROG  =                  150 / CAT_NOPROG                                     
COMMENT = '*       '           / COMMENT                                        
IMATYP  = 'OBJOd/S2D/CAL'      / TACOS_IMATYP                                   
IMALOC  = 'n20011121/s2d/loco0032' / TACOS_IMALOC                               
NORDER  =       6.70000000E+01 / TACOS_NORDER                                   
DECLOC  =       0.00000000E+00 / TACOS_DECLOC                                   
DEGLOC1 =       4.00000000E+00 / TACOS_DEGLOC                                   
DEGLOC2 =       2.50000000E+01 / TACOS_DEGLOC                                   
DEGSIG1 =       3.00000000E+00 / TACOS_DEGSIG                                   
DEGSIG2 =       4.00000000E+00 / TACOS_DEGSIG                                   
OLIMLS  =       1.00000000E+00 / TACOS_OLIMLS                                   
EXTSTR  =       3.00000000E+00 / TACOS_EXTSTR                                   
JDB1    =       2.45223600E+06 / TACOS_JDB                                      
JDB2    =       2.72537142E-01 / TACOS_JDB                                      
BERV    =      -1.91999512E+01 / TACOS_BERV                                     
BERVMX  =       2.33397045E+01 / TACOS_BERVMX                                   
DELCAL  =       0.00000000E+00 / TACOS_DELCAL                                   
DEGXLL  =       3.00000000E+00 / TACOS_DEGXLL                                   
DEGOLL  =       5.00000000E+00 / TACOS_DEGOLL                                   
OLIMLL  =       1.00000000E+00 / TACOS_OLIMLL                                   
LLOFFSET=       1.57015152E+02 / TACOS_LLOFFSET                                 
LLPARS  =      -1.00000000E+00 / TACOS_LLPARS                                   
LLCMOY  =       0.00000000E+00 / TACOS_LLCMOY                                   
LLCSIG  =       0.00000000E+00 / TACOS_LLCSIG                                   
IMACAL  = 'n20011121/llo0033'  / TACOS_IMACAL                                   
LLCNRA  =       1.01300000E+03 / TACOS_LLCNRA                                   
FILERC  = '/d1/gva/dqsrc/elodie/elodiehp' / TACOS_FILERC                        
PROXIM  =       2.50000000E-01 / TACOS_PROXIM                                   
FILENAME= 'elodie:20011121/0036' / Original filename                            
CD1_1   =         0.0500000007 / Coordinate increment per pixel                 
CREATOR = 'Pleinpot     2'     / Written by Pleinpot (Hypercat)                 
DATE-OBS= '2001-11-22T18:27:29' / [CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss] Date observation        
MJD-OBS =         52235.769086 / [d] Modified JD when observ. start             
AIRMASS =           1.00673497 / Airmass                                        
CTYPE1  = 'AWAV    '           / Axis type                                      
H_CONTXT= 'SPE     '           / Spectrum                                       
DATE    = '2020-08-20T15:35:34' / Date (UT) written: CCDD-MM-DDThh:mm:ss        
COMMENT         The ELODIE archive (OHP)                                        
COMMENT  Note: The telescope position (POS1,POS2) and the catalogue information 
COMMENT (NOOBETn)                                                               
COMMENT     may not be accurate. Please use instead the designation from keyword
COMMENT  (OBJECT)                                                               
EXTNAME = 'INTENSITY'                                                           
H_AFR000= 'elodie:20011121/0036' / Archive identifier of current frame          
H_TYPE  =                    1 / Science object                                 
OBJECT  = 'HD214680'           / Object standard designation                    
SN      =                111.1 / S/N-per-pixel of original spectrum at 550 nm   
DIVUL   =                    0 / data fully public                              
H_STATUS=                    0 / No error on pipeline                           
CUNIT1  = '0.1 nm  '           / Unit of coordinate                             
BTYPE   = 'FLUX-INS'           / Type of data                                   
BUNIT   = 'instrumental'       / Unit of data                                   
H_DBIAS =                   0. / [ADU] Bias on the frame                        
H_WRESOL=            0.1321429 / [0.1nm] FWHM wavelength resolution             
H_ASP002= 'fa:LL_ELODIE/99002' / File used for "strengthening"                  
H_HISTO = 'FFC000/WCA000/'                                                      
H_FCANOR= '[FCANOR]'           / Pointer to the Flux calibration relation
```

[image: Полученный спектр]
Каким образом можно построить полосовой эмиссионный спектр на основе имеющихся у меня данных? Буду очень благодарен за помощь!
Результат должен выглядеть примерно так:
[image: Ожидаемый результат]
Или так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю, стоит дать определения непрограммистских терминов, чтобы большее количество человек могло вам теоретически помочь (не в комментариях, а в вопросе, используя кнопку править)

Comment: Что-то даже нагуглить ничего толком по этим терминам не удалось. Что вы хотите построить, как это примерно должно выглядеть?

Comment: Нашёл как раскрасить ваш график в цвета спектра, если что, основываясь на этом вопросе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959955/matplotlib-color-under-curve-based-on-spectral-color